# How to replace one word in a script in Notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

Does anyone know how to replace one word in Notepad++ (for example: CICODE) with several others in order from a list?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWQ0w.png)

Comment: You can't do it in Npp. Write a script in your favorite scripting language (perl, python, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I see is to create your own Notepad++ script. You can read more about it with examples on C# [here](https://nppscripts.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @Toto Comments should be used to clarify the question. I proposed a way to solve the problem. I don't necessarily have to provide full solution. If don't agree you always can flag my answer and moderators will decide.

Comment: You don't provide any answer. So, this is a comment.

Comment: @Toto again I think differently and I explained my point. On the other had you just keep writing that it is not an answer. And again If you don't like something you can flag it and call a moderator or at least try to explain your point.